# Calling functions in Qt from third-party DLL works in debug mode, crashes in release

Tags: qt, dll, release

I use a third-party DLL (FTD2xx) to communicate with an external device. Using Qt4, in debug mode everything works fine, but the release crashes silently after successfully completing a called function. It seems to crash at return, but if I write something to the console (with qDebug) at the end of the function, sometimes it does not crash there, but a few, or few dozen lines later.

I suspect a not properly cleaned stack, what the debug build can survive, but the release chokes on it. Did someone encounter a similar problem? The DLL itself cannot be changed, as the source is not available.

Comment: Perhaps it's optimisation that causes the different behaviour. Try compiling your release version with optimisation disabled, and see what happens. If it works, then you know the bug is still in there somewhere, but you can still ship it...

Comment: I lowered the optimization level, and it (at least for the time being) runs now without crashing. I first suspected a difference between the Qt debug and Qt release DLLs, but it's not the case.

Comment: Are you calling functions contained in the 3rd party DLL from a Qt app, or calling Qt functions from code in the DLL?

Comment: I call functions contained in the 3rd party DLL from the Qt app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the reduction of the optimization level was the only way around. The DLL itself might have problems, as a program which does nothing but calls a single function from that DLL crashes the same way if optimization is turned on.

Fortunately, the size and speed lost by the change in optimization level is negligible.

**Edit**: for anyone with similar problems on Qt 5.0 or higher: If you change the optimization level (for example, to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -O0`), it's usually not enough to just rebuild the application. A full "clean all" is required.

Comment: By the way: which compilers were used for Qt and the DLL?

Comment: Qt 4.7.0 Win32. About the DLL, I didn't compile it myself.

Answer (score -1):

Be warned - the EPANET library is not thread safe, it contains a lot of global variables.

Are you calling two methods of that library from different threads?