# How can one check the optimization level in Qt?

Tags: qt

I [once had a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276225/calling-functions-in-qt-from-third-party-dll-works-in-debug-mode-crashes-in-rel) with an old legacy DLL, which caused a crash in release but worked in debug. Lowering the optimization level solved the problem. I used Qt 4.7 back then, if I remember correctly.

Now, after upgrading to Qt 5.0.1, the same crash happens again, but now both in debug and release. I found the way to set the optimization level in the new Qt, but it does not seem to have any effect:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O3

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O
```

similarly for

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG
```

How can I make sure that those settings are effective? I need to know if the problem is the same as it was in Qt 4.7, or completely unrelated. The crash happens exactly when calling a certain function from the DLL, the same function which caused the problem in Qt 4.7 release with high optimization.

<sub>I cannot even easily downgrade to Qt 4.7, as the SDK is no longer available for download, so I would need a very old and exact mingw version, I know that tiny version differences cause major problems.</sub>

Comment: Most likely, the real issue is somewhere else in your code, and the crash occurring or not is only a **side effect** of the corresponding flags (especially, since you now say that with Qt 5 it appears independent of the setting). Did you try to use valgrind and/or a debugger?

Comment: @Andreas : I used the debugger to see that the crash happens exactly when calling that infamous function from the DLL. In Qt 4.7 the crash happened at the same place, and a change in the optimization settings solved it. Not calling the function leads to no crash, even now. It might be an inherent problem in the DLL, unfortunately, I don't have any source for it.

Comment: Is there a release and a debug version of your DLL? It might be related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you qmake your application, you can clearly see which optimization level was applied. (In the console output log)