# Is there an incompatibility between Qt and STL structures?

Tags: qt, stl

I tried to use `deque` in a Qt application, and strangely, it doesn't seem to work.

I have a Qt class (derived from `QThread`) which works perfectly, but if I declare an `stl::deque<int>` member, it builds successfully but crashes at startup. I don't even use that variable anywhere.

Should STL structures not be used within Qt, expecially in classes inheriting basic Qt classes?

Edit:

```
Thread 3 (Thread 172.0x3bc):
#0  0x7c91e514 in ntdll!LdrAccessResource () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x7c91d21a in ntdll!ZwDelayExecution () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7c8023f1 in SleepEx () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
#3  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (Thread 172.0xb78):
#0  0x7c91e514 in ntdll!LdrAccessResource () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x7c91daaa in ntdll!ZwReplyWaitReceivePortEx () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x77e565e3 in UuidCreate () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll
#3  0x77e56caf in RPCRT4!I_RpcBindingCopy () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll
#4  0x77e56ad1 in RPCRT4!I_RpcBindingCopy () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll
#5  0x77e56c97 in RPCRT4!I_RpcBindingCopy () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll
#6  0x7c80b729 in KERNEL32!GetModuleFileNameA () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
#7  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (Thread 172.0x8d4):
#0  0x7c921689 in ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x7c928ccd in ntdll!RtlRealPredecessor () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0xbaadf00d in ?? ()
#3  0x0a0bc000 in ?? ()
#4  0x7c939ba8 in towlower () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x7c97fb98 in ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x7c95b244 in ntdll!LdrFindEntryForAddress () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#7  0x003e0000 in ?? ()
#8  0x7c929c0c in ntdll!RtlpUnWaitCriticalSection () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x77bfc3c9 in msvcrt!free () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
#10 0x003e0000 in ?? ()
#11 0x77bfc3e7 in msvcrt!free () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
#12 0x00001d40 in ?? ()
#13 0x00224b68 in ?? ()
#14 0x77bfc42e in msvcrt!malloc () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
#15 0x00cef12a in QClipData::initialize (this=0xa093a30) at painting\qpaintengine_raster.cpp:4487
#16 0x00cfa797 in qt_alphamapblit_quint32 (rasterBuffer=0xa099488, x=17, y=207, color=4278190080, map=0xa0ad401 "", mapWidth=9, mapHeight=12, mapStride=256, clip=0xa093a30) at painting\qdrawhelper.cpp:7209
#17 0x00ceb02e in QRasterPaintEngine::alphaPenBlt (this=0x9ff7860, src=0xa0ad401, bpl=256, depth=8, rx=17, ry=207, w=9, h=12) at painting\qpaintengine_raster.cpp:2954
...
```

Stack trace for another run:

```
Thread 3 (Thread 1176.0xb4c):
#0  0x7c91e514 in ntdll!LdrAccessResource () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x7c91d21a in ntdll!ZwDelayExecution () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x7c8023f1 in SleepEx () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
#3  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (Thread 1176.0x71c):
#0  0x7c91e514 in ntdll!LdrAccessResource () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x7c91daaa in ntdll!ZwReplyWaitReceivePortEx () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x77e565e3 in UuidCreate () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll
#3  0x77e56caf in RPCRT4!I_RpcBindingCopy () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll
#4  0x77e56ad1 in RPCRT4!I_RpcBindingCopy () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll
#5  0x77e56c97 in RPCRT4!I_RpcBindingCopy () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll
#6  0x7c80b729 in KERNEL32!GetModuleFileNameA () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
#7  0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (Thread 1176.0x818):
#0  0x7c921689 in ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x7c928ccd in ntdll!RtlRealPredecessor () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Edit2:

The console said "Heap corruption detected" when using `stl::deque`. I switched to using QQueue and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: There is no issue in using both STL and Qt structures together - post some code.

Comment: You can also use containers provided by Qt itself: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qqueue.html

Comment: @cmannett85 : the only code I could post is `#include <deque>` and `stl::deque<int> elements;` because this variable is nowhere been used. The program crashes as soon as calling the `show()` method of the GUI. The constructor of the QThread-derived class is called in the constructor of the GUI, but this `deque` is never used. Which portion of the code are you interested in?

Comment: There must be something else going on, can you post the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: @vsz we are interested in the code that reproduces the crash. Assume for one second that perhaps the error is not in Qt and not in the standard library. What are *you* doing that causes the code to crash in *your* case?

Comment: Also, can you post the full stacktrace of Thread1?

Comment: @Paul unfortunately I don't have it anymore, and it differs for another run.

Comment: Then show us your code. At the very least a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Without it we can't do a whole lot. There is no compatibility problem between Qt and STL.

Comment: @Bart : unfortunately there is nothing in the >3000 lines of code which I found to be in any relation with this problem. I don't use that declared `dequeue` anywhere in my code. I'll start removing parts of the code to isolate what can be the cause besides the dequeue (I tried vector and it also crashes, while removing that single stl declaration does not reproduce the crash), but it will take a long, long time. This is why I asked the question, to see if anyone else had any issues so maybe I don't waste time searching for a solution that is already known.

Comment: This is madness: the source of the problem is an external DLL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276225/calling-functions-in-qt-from-third-party-dll-works-in-debug-mode-crashes-in-rel). Strange that the usage of this queue has nothing to do with the functions of that DLL, so it seems it matters whether STL is compiled into the application or not. That DLL is such a pile of garbage, that even minor differences in compiler version and optimization level affect it.  (By the way, QQueue also causes problems with the DLL when I use it)

Comment: Switching compiler (versions) is always something that breaks compatibility, hence the name mangling. Similarly for MSVC's Debug/Release builds.